# Crash in UIActivityViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

Im getting an crash in my app when i am using UIActivityViewController here  `activityItems: [self.myimage.image!]` :

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
    activityItems: [self.myimage.image!],
    applicationActivities: nil)

self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

myimage is defined as `UIImageView` :

```
@IBOutlet weak var myimage: UIImageView!
```

The stack crash is here :

```
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MyPictures                  0x000000010008e394 @objc MyPictures.DetailController.ActionShare (My.DetailController)(Swift.AnyObject) -> () + 540 (DetailController.swift:95)
1   UIKit                           0x000000018a5f9400 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92 (UIApplication.m:3452)
2   UIKit                           0x000000018a5f9400 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92 (UIApplication.m:3452)
3   UIKit                           0x000000018a5e24dc -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 608 (UIControl.m:647)
4   UIKit                           0x000000018a5f8d9c -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 588 (UIControl.m:417)
5   UIKit                           0x000000018a5b7fbc _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 8532 (UIGestureRecognizer.m:347)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185b3c2a0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1622)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185b3922c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 356 (CFRunLoop.c:1718)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185b3960c __CFRunLoopRun + 832 (CFRunLoop.c:2548)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185a652d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392 (CFRunLoop.c:2795)
10  GraphicsServices                0x000000018f27b6f8 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2245)
11  UIKit                           0x000000018a62afa8 UIApplicationMain + 1484 (UIApplication.m:3039)
12  MyPictures                  0x0000000100091acc main + 152 (AppDelegate.swift:12)
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000197a26a04 start + 0 (start_glue.s:78)
```

Comment: set a breakpoint at the first line and check if `myimage.image` is nil which causes a crash

Comment: @vadian , I've got this crash from iTunes connect not while I'm debugging ! the app is working good in general !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the image is nil that generates a crash, so you should update your code like this:

```
if let image = self.myimage.image{

    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
    activityItems: [image],
    applicationActivities: nil)

    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else{
    // Show some kind of error 
}
```

Comment: Okey sure i will try it then let you know :)

Comment: I recommend you to try to generate the crash before changing the code. For example create a test with self.myimage.image set to nil and try to call the method that generates the UIActivityViewController.

Comment: its saying cannot accept argument with (..uiimage...).

Comment: Please give more details. What type myimage is?

Comment: Take a look at the question myimage is of type `UIImageView` !

Comment: I am really sorry. Where and how do you set self.myimage.image?

Comment: please change activityItems: image to activityItems: [image] to be the correct answer :)